# Android clicks not firing on first tap after activity resumed

Tags: android, xamarin

When our Android activity is resumed, any buttons or views with a click handler registered *do not fire the event on the first tap*. All subsequent taps work fine. It's almost as though the Android activity itself does not have focus.

Answer (score 1):

I found some old code that supposedly hid the navigation bar. Removing it did the trick. The code in question was:

```
    var tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
    tv.SystemUiVisibility =
         (StatusBarVisibility)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
```

Comment: Interesting you asked this question and answered yourself in around 10 seconds?

Comment: You can answer your own questions at the same time as posting the question; it's good for archiving solutions to problems that are really tough to work out but nobody else has an answer. I spent hours trying to figure that one out even after scouring all similar issues scattered around the internet. My issue was unique, so I posted it both for future reference and for somebody else who has that issue.

Comment: I never faced such problem.. maybe you're doing something different. What has activity lifecycle has anything to do with button click listener?